# Yarn memory leak and garbage collection problems

Tags: scala, apache-spark, garbage-collection, hadoop-yarn

I am using Spark over Yarn. But several times, with different applications, I have noticed that Yarn kills a container due to memory exceeding the limit, and that only happens when a Spark executor is executing a task in the 2nd or 3rd iteration. I mean, lets say an executor has to execute 4 tasks serially. The first time it does fine, the second time sometimes also, but the third time it definitely fails due to memory exceeding the limits.

I suspect that somehow the memory in the container keeps on accumulating, that is, the memory used by the previous task is left behind, due to which Yarn kills the container. I especially had this problem when using Maps. But now I'm using Arrays, and also facing the same problem. Did anyone else ever notice this strange mechanism? If yes, what are some solutions to solve it?

Comment: that will depend on what kind of task those previous tasks were. Were they caching things in memory ? Also... all those arrays or maps are impervious for sparks in any kind of memory optimization or memory management. you should use RDD's (or some other construct from Spark's world) which are manageable by Spark.

Comment: I use RDDs wherever possible, but in this case its not possible as I'm running Java programs inside tasks, and I have to prepare data to give them as input.

Comment: All those array will be in-memory without any relation to Spark. And thus you will need to provide the needed memory or else it won't run.

Comment: OK, but I make those arrays inside the functions. Each task executing that function. So, once that function exits, it should clean the Array too. No?